# Format project.pbxproj

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, sh

I created a new project and add a file AppConstans.h
Then, git diff and i see next changes:

```
C856C0AC1C4F4B9900438444 /* AppConstans.h */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; lastKnownFileType = sourcecode.c.h; path = AppConstans.h; sourceTree = "<group>"; };
```

That is OK.  Remove this file.

Now I want to do this with a script.
In run script add this:

```
echo "/* AppConstans */" > ${PROJECT_DIR}/AppConstans.h
```

The file is created, and be in a folder with the project. Now it is necessary to add to the project. I want change project.pbxproj file and add the following line manually :

```
C856C0AC1C4F4B9900438444 /* AppConstans.h */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; lastKnownFileType = sourcecode.c.h; path = AppConstans.h; sourceTree = "<group>"; };
```

But I do not understand how to code this line here.

I have rootObject:

```
rootObject = C856C08A1C4F4B7E00438444 /* Project object */;
```

I have AppDelegate.h

```
C856C0981C4F4B7E00438444 /* AppDelegate.h */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; lastKnownFileType = sourcecode.c.h; path = AppDelegate.h; sourceTree = "<group>"; };
```

So it should look like file format

```
C856C0AC1C4F4B9900438444 /* AppConstans.h */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; lastKnownFileType = sourcecode.c.h; path = AppConstans.h; sourceTree = "<group>"; };
```

Diff between AppDelegate.h and AppConstans.h and root object code C856C08A1C4F4B7E00438444

C856C**08A1**C4F4B**7E**00438444 (root object code)

C856C**0981**C4F4B**7E**00438444 (app delegate)

C856C**0AC1**C4F4B**99**00438444 (app constants)

I can not create here such code to create a file via a script. Any ideas ?
Any help would be appreciated

Update:

I create new project. This is project three:

[image]

Step 2:

I add new script and run:

[image]

Step 3:

See project thee again. The file is not in project dir:

[image]

Step 4: Open project dir in finder: And I see AppConstans.h was created. But file not added in project. I must added him manually.

[image]

Step 5: I added file mutually, and I see changes in pbxproj
[image]

So, how i can convert name AppConstants.h  to C8F3552E1C57A366003D3D39

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
echo "/* AppConstans */" >> "${PROJECT_DIR}/AppConstans.h"
```

Notice the `>>` instead of the `>` (and the quotes around the path, to prevent expansion). This will cause your string to be appended to the end of the file instead of replacing the file.

Comment: Nothing happened. File was created. But It did't add to my project automatically. This line create AppConstans.h and write /* AppConstans */ to top.

Comment: I thought that was what it was supposed to do. Could you please edit your answer and write exactly what you want to happen?

Answer (score 0):

A framework you can use for this is [PBXproject](https://github.com/owlforestry/pbxproject). Open the .pbxproj file, create a new file reference, and save the file.